# How to replace the global exception handler in JUnit 4.12 with one printing "root cause first" stack trace?

Tags: java, junit, exception, logback

I would like to have the excellent ["root cause first" stack trace](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2011/09/logging-exceptions-root-cause-first.html) when a `Throwable` is being thrown from my `JUnit 4.12` test. I tried the following, but setting the uncaught exception handler has no effect:

```
package repro;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class JavaScratchpadTest
{
  @Test
  public void someTest()
  {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
      public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
      {
        // The root logger is configured to print out the "root cause first" stack trace.
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(org.slf4j.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME).error("err: ", e);
      }
    });
    throw new RuntimeException("ex1", new Exception("ex2"));
  }
}
```

I deduced from the stack trace and JUnit source inspection that one solution might possibly be to provide my own (replace existing?) [RunListener](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener.html) but I am not sure.

Comment: This a very interesting feature, and it's a good question.  However it's worth calling out that needing to print root-cause-first stack traces often is a sign of existing poor design.  Wrapping exceptions are supposed to provide more meaningful context than their causes, not less.  Obviously there are countless cases where the wrapper fails to do so, or where you really do need to inspect the cause, but if it's happening so often you want to inspect the cause first by default, consider trying to improve the wrapping exceptions first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `Runner` that adds a `RunListener`, e.g.

```
public class MyTestRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

  public MyTestRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
    super(klass);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
    notifier.addListener(new RunListener() {
        @Override
        public void testFailure(Failure failure) throws Exception {
            Throwable exception = failure.getException();
            //insert your logs here
        }
    });
    super.run(notifier);
  }

}
```

Yet this allows you to log as you want.

Probably you want to change the JUnit reporting, too. This seems to be quite difficult, perhaps reflection could help.

Comment: This works after I annotate the `JavaScratchpadTest` class with `@RunWith(MyTestRunner.class)` and insert my logging in `MyTestRunner.run()`. However, now I have two stack traces being printed out: first the default one, then the "root cause first" one. Looks like the default stack trace is printed out by `com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4TestResultsSender` (`extends RunListener`)  which is presumably present because I am running the test from IntelliJ IDEA. I do not know if it is possible to get rid of it.